# How to convert numeric numbers to time stamp using R

Tags: r, datetime, timestamp, numeric

I used this script

```
 df?timestamp< as.POSIXct(df$timestamp,tz="",format="%Y%m%d%H%M%S",origin = "1970-01-01")
```

then i get NA's.

The number i have is 43466.10 and the result i should get is 2019-01-01 02:17:26.

What am i supposed to do?

Comment: Are you sure about the `origin` ? `as.POSIXct(43466.10, origin = '1970-01-01')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, 43466.10 is not a valid Unix epoch time. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time for more information.

This number looks like an Excel date/time value. If that truly is, then "2019-01-01 02:17:26" is actually 43466.0954398148, and the origin you should use is "1899-12-30", not "1970-01-01".

You cannot use `as.POSIXct` directly in this case because UNIX epoch time is in counting **seconds**, but an Excel date/time value is in counting **days**.

You can use the package `openxlsx` to do this conversion. Try this:

```
# install.packages("openxlsx")
df$timestamp <- openxlsx::convertToDateTime(df$timestamp, origin = "1899-12-30")
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you.